# python function with unexpected sqlite3 printout result

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to printout some commands in my database but now it printout unexpected answer. Let me show you my code first. x and y are the things that I need to search in my database and get some command

```
x="create vlan"
y="global"

def readswitch(x,y):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
    if conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()
        run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
        read = cur.fetchall()
        return run;

import database
print (database.readswitch(x,y))
```

but now the results are as followed

```
C:\Python34\python.exe C:/Users/tommy/PycharmProjects/2015122/database.py
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002753CE0>
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x0000000002753DC0>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I did not see this result before !
What problem is it?

Comment: `return read` instead of `return run` ?

Comment: @Jon Clements Wow!!!! You are correct very so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are returning the cursor instead of fetched data in your readswitch function.
the run object is not needed at all

instead of

```
  cur = conn.cursor()
  run= cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
  read = cur.fetchall()
  return run;
```

you probably need

```
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute("SELECT command FROM switch WHERE   function =? or type = ?  ORDER BY key ASC",(x,y))
  read = cur.fetchall()
  return read;
```